# Form not sending out select and checkbox inputs in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm working on a small Angular 2 To-do app. I didn't want to have any problems with browser compatibility with inputs types like date, datetime-local, etc., so I did make `<select>` inputs for user to type in the date and time. Everything works fine, inputs are dynamic, so the user cannot choose the day that does not exist (like e.g. 02/29/2017), etc.

The problem is, I want to send form's data to the service and then to the Back-End of my app, but when I submit the form, values from `<select>` inputs are not included in the sent object, as well as my checkbox input. I'm not often using these types of inputs, so I'm sorry if this is a noobish question, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add(f.value)">

    <div *ngIf="error">
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="login-input-container">
        <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title" ngModel autocomplete="off" required minlength="1" maxlength="100">
    </div> 
    <div class="login-input-container">
        <div class="datetime-container">
            <div>
                <select #year name="year" (change)="showMonths(); selectedYear = year.value; yearDays(year.value);" required>
                    <option class="invisible" value="" disabled selected>year</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year" placeholder="year">{{ year }}</option>
                </select>
                <select #month *ngIf="showedMonths" name="month" (change)="showDays(month.value, year.value); selectedMonth = month.value;" required>
                    <option class="invisible" value="" disabled selected>M</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month">{{ month }}</option>
                </select>
                <select *ngIf="showedDays" name="day" (change)="showTime()" required>
                    <option class="invisible" value="" disabled selected>d</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">{{ day }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showedTime">
                <select name="hours" required>
                    <option class="invisible" value="" disabled selected>hh</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let hour of hours" [value]="hour">{{ hour }}</option>
                </select>
                :
                <select name="minutes" required>
                    <option class="invisible" value="" disabled selected>mm</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let minute of minutes" [value]="minute">{{ minute }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="login-input-container">
        <textarea id="todo-description" type="text" placeholder="description (optional)" name="description" ngModel autocomplete="off" minlength="1" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="login-input-container">
        <span><p>should we notify you?</p><label for="notify-1"><input id="notify-1" type="checkbox" [checked]="todo.notify" value="1"><span></span></label></span>
    </div> 
    <div class="login-input-container">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="error = ''">
    </div> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `[value]` or `[ngValue]` you need to use `[(ngModel)]` or `ngModel (ngModelChange)="showMonths()..."` instead of `(change)="..."

Comment: Thank you. I've just added the ngModels to the inputs that didn't work, but there's another problem - it doesn't want to work while I have the *ngIf conditionals on these inputs. They are pretty important for me.

Comment: What does "it" and "doesn't want to work" mean exactly?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I did a mistake while reading the error log. I put the ngModel on the checkbox and I don't have the name specified there. Thank you for your answer.